# Why do I get wrong alignment in this if I use bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

If I use bootstrap, it messes the alignment up on my page. Member names should be appeared right next to icon, but with Bootstrap, they overlap the icon.
How can I fix this?

[image]

Also, when the browser window is made smaller, the square line gets messed up too. I want the data to have a border when the window is small.

So I don't want it to look like this:

[image]

But rather, like this:

[image]

If possible I want to have these icon, and name in middle not on the top.

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/sbq7X/

**HTML**

```
    <div class="store_row">
    <div class="store_left">
        <div class="store_title">walmart</div>
        <div class="store_location">Located in California</div>
    </div>

    <div class="store_right">
        <div class="store_icon">
                <img class="img-polaroid" src="http://www.miraiha.net/wpblog/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/designreviver-free-twitter-social-icon-300x266.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="introduction">
            <div class="name1">John Tailor</div>
            <div class="name2">Mike Smith</div>
            <div class="name3">Jessica Swan</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

    <div class="store_row">
    <div class="store_left">
        <div class="store_title">walmart</div>
        <div class="store_location"><span class='text-error'>Located in California</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="store_right">
        <div class="store_icon">
                <img class="img-polaroid" src="http://media-cache-ec1.pinterest.com/avatars/walmarthub-1349815045_600.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="introduction">
            <div class="name1">John Tailor</div>
            <div class="name2">Mike Smith</div>
            <div class="name3">Jessica Swan</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.store_row{
    min-width: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border:1px solid;
    display:table;
}

div.store_left{
    width: 300px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;    
}

div.store_right{
    width: 300px;   
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

div.store_title{
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 35px;
    padding:5px;
}

div.store_location{
    height: 35px;  
    border-right:1px solid;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding:5px;
}

div.store_icon{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    display:inline-block;
}

div.store_icon img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

div.introduction{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:200px;
    text-align: left;
}

.... and bootstrap
```

Comment: Well, it sure has something to do with all that Bootstrap CSS, because without it, [it looks just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/YnVRb/).

Comment: How can I make it okay?:(

Comment: Find the conflicting style. Eliminate all, and add bit by bit until it doesn't perform well. Then make de decision about how to correct your or Bootstraps styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`img-polaroid` class has 4px padding and it causes the problem:

```
.img-polaroid {
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uzYBN/) where it's removed.

EDIT: The alignment is working fine as well. You have static width for the all elements and they're too wide for fiddle. I've decreased their size so they are inline now.